# What exactly files whose names' prefix is "AT.postflight." are needed for?

Tags: bash, files, osx, symlink, locate

I am not sure if this question should be asked here, since I am on an OS X, but since I am using `bash`, and I am asking about the meaning and the purposes of some files.

I am trying to understand why a certain program (`Designer.app`), that comes with the official `Qt` distribution (version 5.5) that I had installed a while ago, keeps crashing. At the following link you can find more information about this problem if you are interested:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149008/how-to-delete-possible-symbolic-links-created-by-anaconda?noredirect=1#comment52187516_32149008

Apparently, I think, the problem is related to the fact that a dynamic library (`libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib`) is missing , but when I use the following command to locate the library `locate libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib`, I have a strange output:

```
/Users/cell/anaconda/lib/libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib
/Users/cell/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.6-0/lib/libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib
/Users/cell/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.6-2/lib/libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib
/Users/cell/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.6-3/lib/libQtDesignerComponents.4.dylib
```

This is strange because I have no more the directory `anaconda`.

What could be causing this strange output, and how can I solve this problem? I thought this could be due to some symbolic links...

My main question is anyway the following. In the meantime, I have found some files (exactly 6 files) on my home directory whose purposes are unknown for me. The filenames are prefixed with `AT.postflight.`, and then the suffixes are numbers.  The first one for example called `AT.postflight.1174` contains the following contents:

```
Has /Library/Tcl/teapot = 0
HOME______ = /Users/cell
USER______ = cell
pkgdir____ = /Volumes/ActiveTcl-8.6/ActiveTcl-8.6.pkg
installdir = /
repository = /Library/Tcl/teapot
shell_____ = /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6
Having a seed repository.
No existing repository, copying the seed to the repository-to-be at /Library/Tcl/teapot
/usr/local/bin/teacup link make /Library/Tcl/teapot /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6
Ok
/usr/local/bin/teacup default /Library/Tcl/teapot
/Library/Tcl/teapot
Forcing ownership of /Users/cell/Library/Application Support/ActiveState to cell
___done
```

This seems to be related to Tcl packages... The other files seem to contain similar contents...

What are the purposes of these files? Can I safely delete them?

Answer (score 1):

These files are leftovers from a failed, interrupted, or buggy macOS package installation.

The files themselves may be safely removed, but the package that the installer installed may not have installed properly.

As for the `locate` showing non-existent files and directories: The `locate` command may show files in places that no longer exist if you have recently deleted those file hierarchies.  The `locate` database is rebuilt periodically (this happens once a week according to the `locate.updatedb` manual on macOS).